# Выбор из текста нужных цифр

Tags: php

Есть TXT документы. Проименованные с 1 до 300. В каждом документе текст (на русском) в котором есть числа. Некоторые числа это просто числа, а некоторые - ссылки на другие документы.

Пример:
"Шум толпы постепенно стихает по мере того, как ты все дальше углубляешься в
темные бездны туннеля. Через каждые 20 метров с потолка свисают гигантские
кристаллы, испуская тусклый свет, достаточный, чтобы ты мог разглядеть неровный пол
под ногами. Постепенно твои глаза привыкают к окружающему полумраку, и ты
начинаешь понимать, что вокруг царит ни на миг не прекращающееся движение.
Скрываясь при твоем приближении, в расщелинах высеченных в скале стен ползают
многочисленные пауки и сороконожки, под ногами снуют крысы и мыши. Разнося
зловещее эхо, с высокого свода то и дело срываются и падают в лужи зловонной жидкости
мутные капли. Воздух холодный, сырой и промозглый. Пройдя по туннелю несколько
минут, ты приближаешься к каменному алтарю, стоящему слева у стены. На алтаре стоит
шесть шкатулок, на крышке одной из них вырезано твое имя. Если хочешь открыть
шкатулку, иди на 270. Если хочешь пройти мимо, иди на 66."

20 - просто цыфра.
270, 66 - ссылки на документы.

Что должно в итоге получиться: Веб страница в которой подгружается текст из TXT файла и вместо цифры-ссылки подставляется гиперссылка на документ с именем совпадающим с цифрой-ссылкой.

Столкнулся с проблемой - не могу придумать как из текста выбирать нужные мне цифры.

Comment: Оставляете только цифры, сверяете цифры по тем самым нужным ссылочным цифрам, заменяете на ссылку, то, что не найдено в ссылочных цифрах, будут просто числа, профит.

Comment: Извините, я наверно не совсем корректно описал свою проблему. Поправил пример. Дело в том что алгоритму ведь без разницы какие это цифры + цифры в тексте могут попадать в диапазон 1-300, но не все они должны подменяться на ссылки.

Comment: Еще раз повторяю, сверяйте те, которые попадают под ссылочные, раз документы, берите массив документов и найденные цифры прогоняйте по массиву сформированный из документов, если цифра подходит под один из документов, значит это ссылка, если нет, значит обычное цисло, что непонятного?

Comment: Единственная зависимость, которая прослеживается в этом фрагменте текста: `Если хочешь ..., иди на ...`, где второе троеточие и есть ссылочный маркер.

Comment: У меня в примере  3-и цифры. Если пройтись по тексту алгоритмом, то он заменит все 3-и цифры на ссылки так-как они все попадают диапазон 1-300, а это неверно.

Comment: перед ссылками всегда есть, извините, "иди на"? если нет, то как еще можно отличить число от ссылки?

Comment: перед нужными числами текст всегда разный. И именно в этом сложность. Нет никакой статики за которую можно было бы зацепиться. Собственно именно поэтому и решил спросить. Может я чего не знаю и есть "инструменты" которые бы помогли бы в этом...

Comment: тексты будут меняться? их будет больше 300? мжб просто собрать по текстам все места со ссылками и пометить их как-нибудь, или собрать все характерные префиксные слова

Comment: Тексты буду меняться. Их будет больше 300, примерно до 10к. Единственный вариант на сегодняшний день - лезть в каждый документ руками и как либо выделять нужные цифры Либо префиксы, либо кавычки в виде спецсимволов.

Comment: Что толку вам объяснять, если вы понимать не хотите? Вот в чем вам не устраивает мой совет о сборе инфы по файлу? Открыли текст, оставили только числа собрали массив из этих чисел, все, теперь у вас есть `TXT документы. Поименованные с 1 до 300` - вот и сделайте массив их этих поименованных файлов, гоняем массив по массиву поименованных файлов, профит!

Comment: Ок, вот как будет работать ваш вариант. У меня в тексте будет 3-5 цифр и он все заменит на ссылки. А по факту там нет цифр которые должны быть ссылками. Вопрос как мне поможет массив ненужных мне цифр ?

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы число 20 обычное и число 20 не обычное, для этого есть массив цифровых ссылок и массив документов для этик цифровых ссылок, цифровые ссылки, конечно же стоит пометить, ибо 20 одинаковых числа без какой либо последовательности отличить не удастся, если только сделать чтобы эти числа стояли до или после каких то определенных символов или же строк, слов, фраз.. [есть такой еще вариант](https://regex101.com/r/40X8sn/11) (на скорую руку) можно сделать и более сложные шаблоны для различия цифр.

Comment: НО если у вас совпадения по цифрам не будет то я говорю, можно сделать скан документов по имени и уже номер документа сверять с цифрой в тексте. /Способов на самом деле много.